# Script Code Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

My autocomplete and datetimepicker scripts conflicts. It is, therefore, datepicker not work. I try noConflict() method but, it's not work for me. I must use these two script codes.

My script codes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#projeadi").autocomplete("projeler.php", {
        selectFirst: true
  });
 });
</script>



<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
    $.datepicker.regional['tr'] = {
        closeText: 'kapat',
        prevText: '&#x3c;geri',
        nextText: 'ileri&#x3e',
        currentText: 'bugün',
        monthNames: ['Ocak','Şubat','Mart','Nisan','Mayıs','Haziran',
        'Temmuz','Ağustos','Eylül','Ekim','Kasım','Aralık'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Oca','Şub','Mar','Nis','May','Haz',
        'Tem','Ağu','Eyl','Eki','Kas','Ara'],
        dayNames: ['Pazar','Pazartesi','Salı','Çarşamba','Perşembe','Cuma','Cumartesi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Pz','Pt','Sa','Ça','Pe','Cu','Ct'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Pz','Pt','Sa','Ça','Pe','Cu','Ct'],
        weekHeader: 'Hf',
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['tr']);
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
  });
</script>
```

How I solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: I not get any error, but datepicker not working.

Comment: Actually conflict occur when you using Jquery and some other tool like Mootool. As you have autocompleter and datepicker there should not be any conflict. Try to find out solution by debugging code.

Comment: debug is giving these errors:                                                          TypeError: dpDiv.delegate is not a function  jquery-ui.js:2299:9
TypeError: t.delegate is not a function   jquery-ui.min.js:6:2878
TypeError: a(...).on is not a function   bootstrap.min.js:6:1434
TypeError: e.datepicker is undefined   jquery-ui.min.js:7:6033

Comment: seems you need to add one more js `jquery-ui.min.js`. Add it and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved my problem. I edited jquery.js and autocomplete.js, I changed "$" to "jQuery" in the these jquery.js and autocomplete.js . After these I change my script code to

```
<script>
 var $cakisma = jQuery.noConflict();
 $cakisma(document).ready(function(){
  $cakisma("#projeadi").autocomplete("projeler.php", {
    selectFirst: true
  });
 });
</script>
```

and it's worked like a charm. Thanks for help everyone.